# When @Test method is entered, SpringApplication logs do not show

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, slf4j, spring-boot-test

I'm currently setting up a SpringBoot test and I'd like to see the log output of my applications while it is running.

However when the @Test method begins execution, none of the application's logs show and the intelliJ's "Run" Terminal is blank.

How do I see the log output of the application while the @Test method is executing?
(My application is using Slf4j logger)

Comment: Can you show us your logger config? (logback xml)

Comment: Plus, you can have a different logging config for your tests by adding `logback-test.xml` under `src/test/resources` if you don't want to modify your other config.

Comment: Or there can be settings in `application.properties` in `src/main/resources` or `src/test/resources` as well.

Comment: I don't seem to have a logback.xml file, does SpringBoot take care of this in the background maybe?

Comment: I have the logging.level set to Debug, in my application.yml file

Comment: @Guilty - did you find a solution to this? I also don't see any logs which are otherwise seen when running the application. Only when the tests are executing no logs are seen on the intellij console